# Time formatting string in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

Why is "Y" for "Year" capitalized while "m" for month is not? Moreover, "M" for minute is capitalized!

`Time.now.strftime "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`

I always have difficulty to remember that as an english as second language programmer.

Methods of how to memorize the above formatting notation or explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Just memorize it, man. It's not that difficult

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I just want to know the reason why it is designed like that(if there is a reason). If there's no rules, I will memorize it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%Y` is capitalized because it's long form year (2013). You can use `%y` and it will produce short form (13).

Also all parts in time section should be capitalized, because their lower-case variants are already taken by something else (in parentheses I provided current values).

```
`%h` - human short name for month (Jun)
`%H` - hour (14)

`%m` - month (06)
`%M` - minute (09)

`%s` - unixtime (1370599766)
`%S` - second
```

Simple, no?

> If there's no rules, I will memorize it

Just memorize :)